# Inserting plots inside code chunks in R Markdowns

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, error-handling, r-markdown

I'm trying to add a plot to my R Markdown report, however, when I try to knit what I have yet written I found myself with a disastrous error. I have changed a lot of arguments and parameters in order to show the plot on my Markdown.

[This is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6wCB.png)

I'd like you to help me fix this error so that I can show  all the plots I need.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've spelled `hours` correctly. The error suggests you don't have a variable `hours` in your dataset. Perhaps it ought to be capitalized?